# Cassandra CQL selecting rows with has values different on two columns

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I create table:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
            I int PRIMARY KEY,
            A text,
            B text
);
```

Than I add two columns `X` and `Y` using:

```
ALTER TABLE T ADD X int;
CREATE INDEX ON T (X);
ALTER TABLE T ADD Y int;
CREATE INDEX ON T (Y);
```

I put some data and now I would like to count rows which has different values on `X` and `Y` (even `X` < `Y` would be fine). I tried something like this:

```
select COUNT(*) from T where X < Y ;
```

This also doesn't work without `COUNT` - just simple `*`.

But I'm getting error `no viable alternative at input ';'`
Do you have some suggestions how to overcome this error?
I tried using counters instead of integers but they forced me to put all non-counter data to primary key which wasn't good idea in my case ...

I'm using Cassandra 1.2.6 and CQL 3.

PS can I perform UPDATE on all rows? without `WHERE` clause or with some dummy one?

Comment: your Y variable is not indexed.  Have you tried creating index on Y and then run the query.

Comment: They are indexed.. just presented example how I add them and how I set index on one table ..

Comment: you could have a look at CQL reference. i think this kind of relational query is not supported. for details plz read : http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#selectStmt

Comment: I'm afraid that you are right :/

Answer (score 0):

As Cassandra prefers simple reads the Cassandra-way to do this is to insert a boolean flagged column on update/insert. With an (secondary) index you may query the reads faster as well.